# Make your PC (Software to use?) as a phone with a router with a VOIP capabilities

Tags: windows-7, networking, audio, microphone, voip

I have a modem TD- VG3631. It has a VOIP on it. I can connect my phone to use VOIP.. But How can I use my pc as a phone because my pc already has a mic, speaker and a cam. Is that even possible? My OS is a Windows 7. I am a layman in this kind of tech. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, What your looking for is called a softphone now your problem will be bandwidth management you need to enable QOS and pick a compression solution to resolve any bandwidth limitations you have

Comment: Im stock in configuration now. I just apply the SIP on my Modem and on the Softphone 3CX. But I could not connect to the server.

Comment: Your VOIP-modem is a VOIP/SIP-**client**. It does have a pass-through for the phone-line (for emergencies and incoming landline-calls) but it needs a SIP-**provider** (or your own SIP-server) to make calls over the internet. You can't connect a SIP-client (soft-phone) to it to make calls over your landline without a SIP-provider (because it does not have the SIP-server part in it).

Comment: But checking on my modem, it has a SIP account on it...  and it says that the status is up, so we can use the normal phone.. I also noticed in the 3cx softphone yo need to enter the sip account.

Comment: Then you already have a SIP-account with a provider. It is [not advised](http://wiki.voip.ms/article/FAQ#Can_I_register_2_different_devices_with_the_same_account_.3F) to use 1 account for 2 devices (end result may be that only your soft-phone will ring on incoming calls). You could set up your own SIP-server internally to manage the routing of calls etc. (not easy to setup) or you can inquire with your SIP-provider if you can have [Sub-account](http://wiki.voip.ms/article/Sub_Accounts) (if they have that possibility).

Comment: @Rik Thank you very much. It is okay for me to receive incoming calls. So do you mean that I can use the SIP entered on the Modem?

Comment: If your soft-modem is registering the same account *it can be* that the normal phone won't ring anymore on incoming calls. That is, when your SIP-provider only allows one registered device per account. You can try it yourself if you know the password and account info of that account. If it doesn't work you can always switch the modem off and on again and all is back to normal. (i.e. modem will re-register itself and ring again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many soft-phone solutions for Windows. I've used [eye-beam](http://www.counterpath.com/eyebeam.html) quite successfully.

Comment: Oh, so it is called soft-phone. I tried to use the 3CX because it is free. It ask for a SIP something data.. Then I check my modem and click the voip option it also has a SIP.

Comment: is asking assistance for SIP setup another question? Or is it allowed here? thanks.